# Should I rewrite all the existing jquery ajax webparts in Typescript or is it better to inject existing jquery in SPFX?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts

We are moving from SharePoint 2013 to SharePoint Online. We are thinking of migrating existing webparts in 2013, which have jquery - ajax, to SPFX client webparts. Do we have to rewrite all the code in Typescript? Or, can we inject the existing jquery ajax in Typescript?

Answer (score 4):

A great reference when planning this move is `[Migrate existing customization to the SharePoint Framework][1]` in the SharePoint Framework documentation. Unfortunately, there isn't an answer that would fit every situation.

Here's a relevant quote from that section regarding whether or not you'll need to rewrite:

> Given the variety of JavaScript libraries, there is no easy way to tell upfront if your existing scripts can be reused in a SharePoint Framework solution or if you need to rewrite it after all. The only way to determine this is by trying to move the different pieces to a SharePoint Framework solution and see if they work as expected.

For jQuery, in general, there is also some good guidance out there when moving to TypeScript. jQuery, in itself, [can and is used in Typescript code](https://www.kodfor.com/Using-jQuery-in-TypeScript). From [How to use jQuery with TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32050645/how-to-use-jquery-with-typescript):

> Most likely you need to download and include the TypeScript definition file for jQuery—jquery.d.ts—in your project.